# Select from one table and order by column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to MySQL and I couldn't find any solution for this problem. I appreciate for all kind of helps.

I have table A and table B which interrelated. I wish to select from table A and make the result order by 'date' column of Table B. This 2 tables are link by 'user_id'. My tables are as below:

```
Table A: 
... 
name 
user_id (link to table B)

Table B: 
user_id 
date
```

Is it possible to do that? Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do an inner join.  Something like:

```
 Select A.user_id, A.name, B.date from A
 INNER JOIN B ON B.user_id = A.user_id
 WHERE (whatever your filtering is)
 ORDER BY B.date
```

You should do some research on joining, as it is a very important and vital thing for database development (and knowing a good deal about it helps build good architecture).

The gist of it is that for every user_id in A, I want to find the matching user_id in B (because of the line INNER JOIN B ON B.user_id = A.user_id).  An inner join only brings in what matches, so if A has an ID of 2, but there are no IDs of 2 in B, it will not return the record (similar for records in B without a record in A).

Now, one thing to note is that if I have one record in A with a user ID of 5, but two records in B with a user ID of 5, an inner join returns two records, joining the A data with each of the B data.

Now, as your comment to this question asked, you want to get the higher rating, you want a maximum function.

```
 Select A.user_id, A.name, B.date, Max(B.rating) from A
 INNER JOIN B ON B.user_id = A.user_id
 WHERE (whatever your filtering is)
 GROUP BY A.user_id
 ORDER BY B.date
```

This has two parts, the aggregate function Max() and the Group By statement.  These work together so that for every unique A.user_id, the database will return the recordset with the highest B.rating.  You can also use functions like Min() which is the opposite, selecting the lowest B.rating, or Count() which will count the occurrences of the record, or Sum() which will add together the records for that column.

As always with database queries, play around with them, make sure you get the correct data returned and you understand why.  When I build queries, I usually start with  select * from table, figure out what I need to join in, verifying along the way my records look good, then start limiting columns and filtering things.  Your mileage may vary on the method, but verifying data is always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now I have another question again. Let say I have another column 'rating' in table B. If I have one record in A with a user ID of 5, but two records in B with a user ID of 5, and I only want to select one record in B which has the higher rating, how should I do that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` both tables with `user_id`, select the required columns from `TableA` and add a `ORDER BY` clause with `date` field from `TableB`.

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TableA T1 JOIN
     TableB T2 ON T1.user_id=T2.user_id
ORDER BY T2.date
```

Learn more about `JOIN`s [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [**here**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm).